# Pass JSON array to function in React as props and then count items in area

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Apologies.  Newbie here having problems with passing a JSON object into a function as props.  I'm obviously doing something wrong but I've searched and other people's posts seem more complex than mine.

I want to pass an array which may have zero or more rows into a function and then I want to count how many rows there are.  Finally I would return a string depending on that.  I've got the last part working but I can't pass the array without getting undefined.

App.js

```jsx
const sampleTeams = [
  {
    team: "Jets",
    season: "2022/23",
    regfee: 35,
    feepaid: true,
  },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
    <MemberCard
      forename="Bob"
      surname="Jones"
      playerNumber="154"
      registrations={sampleTeams}
    ></MemberCard>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

MemberCard.js

```jsx
export default function MemberCard({
  forename,
  surname,
  memberNumber,
  registrations,
}) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title className="d-flex justify-content-between slign-items-baseline fw-normal mb-3">
          <div className="me-2">
            {forename} {surname}
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex align-items-baseline text-muted fs-6 ms-1">
            {memberNumber}
          </div>
        </Card.Title>
        <p>{getNumberOfTeams({ registrations })} registered</p>
        <Stack direction="horizontal" gap="2" className="mt-4">
          <Button variant="outline-primary" className="ms-auto">
            Register Team
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

function getNumberOfTeams(registrations) {
  const numberOfTeams = registrations.length;
  // console.log(numberOfTeams);
  if (numberOfTeams === 1) return "1 team";
  return numberOfTeams + " teams";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, there is the object shorthand in the argument of the call to `getNumberOfTeams`

```js
getNumberOfTeams({ registrations })
```

The function `getNumberOfTeams(registrations)` attempts to read `registrations.length`, but you passed it an object `{ registrations: registrations }`. `Object.length` will always be `undefined`. Your code should work more correctly if you change it to

```
        <p>{getNumberOfTeams(registrations)} registered</p>
```